# Rename lowercase folder to uppercase

Tags: bash, rename, filenames, case-insensitive, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to rename folders from lowercase to uppercase. For example

```
abc ABC
twoshirts TwoShirts
```

I've tried

```
mv -T -f source destination
```

I've tried a few different combination but I get an error

> Error moving files as they are the same file or sub directory of itself.

Is it possible to do it with mv?

Comment: Your filesystem might be case insensitive. Are you using macOS?

Comment: Ubuntu on Windows 10

Comment: Have you tried without the `-T` flag? Like so, `mv folder Folder`?

Comment: Yes I have I get a `abc is a subdirectory to itself` error.

Comment: This might help: [How to Enable Case Sensitive File and Folder Names on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/354220/how-to-enable-case-sensitive-folders-on-windows-10/)

Comment: Enable case sensitivity: https://superuser.com/questions/1371215/

Comment: Thank you. That worked for me. If you can put that into an answer I'll accept it @Cyrus

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your file system is case-insensitive; UNIX and its derivatives like Linux have traditionally had case-sensitive filesystems, but Windows doesn't. So you have to first rename the file to some other name, and then from there to the target name.

e.g. `mv abc notabc; mv notabc ABC`

Comment: That's what I'm doing now. I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Nope, not on a case-insensitive file system. Sorry.

Comment: I've done it on Windows 10 Ubuntu before. I had to format my laptop and had to re-install Ubuntu. It doesn't work after that.

Comment: You can make the filesystem case-sensitive, but most Windows apps and utilities tend not to like that.